# Objects composition of NEventStore components for DI

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, event-sourcing, object-composition, neventstore

I'm adding NEventStore to my existing project and I'm using DI.

I'd like to have an instance of `CommonDomain.Persistence.EventStore.IRepository` injected into my MVC controller. [The only implementation](https://github.com/NEventStore/NEventStore/blob/master/src/NEventStore/CommonDomain/Persistence/EventStore/EventStoreRepository.cs#L24) of this interface is `EventStoreRepository`.
This class depends on `IConstructAggregates` and the [only implementation I find](https://github.com/NEventStore/NEventStore/blob/master/src/NEventStore.Tests/CommonDomain/Persistence/IAggregatePersistenceTestHelpers.cs) is `AggregateFactory` which is marked as internal, located in test project and has very strange file name.

Am I not supposed to use `IRepository`? (why is it marked as public and not consumed by any of the internal code?)
I'm looking on sample project [here](https://github.com/luizdamim/NEventStoreExample/blob/master/NEventStoreExample/CommandHandler/CloseAccountCommandHandler.cs#L20) and `IRepository` used for manipulating of the aggregates.

Or should I implement `IConstructAggregates` myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm struggling with the same thing, I think the short answer is:

If you're not using snapshots, the implementation in the test project would work fine.  In fact, I'd add some code to throw an exception if you were given a snapshot.

If you are using snapshots, you'd have to use an approach similar to the one at the end of the one described here: http://williamverdolini.github.io/2014/08/20/cqrses-neventstore-snapshots/

Essentially, the issue is that the object that you'd return from IConstructAggregates will have the event stream replayed on it **starting at the version immediately following the snapshot that is passed in**.

Just a guess, but I think the reason this may not be "officially" implemented in CommonDomain is:

- If you have Aggregates that support snapshots, you have to implement `GetSnapshot()` on them anyway, and you'd want to build an `IConstructAggregates` implementation that can re-hydrate those Aggregates somehow (maybe an `ISupportSnapshots` interface?)
- It's possible that you'd want to use your DI container to build your Aggregate rather than just `Activator.CreateInstance<T>()`.

Looks like this snippet of code here uses the same logic as the `AggregateFactory` from the test project:
- http://pastebin.com/cFESMiTz

Comment: I think I have found the reason for this class not to be publicly-supported: it seems to be incomplete and not properly tested. I'm having a range of problems with this repository and already filed a bug-report: https://github.com/NEventStore/NEventStore/issues/376

Comment: And no, no snapshots for me, but I think I'll have to avoid this class anyway, as I'm stumbling into major issues using it -(

Comment: I think I'm going to end up using something like geteventstore.com and using a modified-version of the CommonDomain project.  I'm finding a few things there need a little bit of adjustment to work for my situation.

Comment: Yep, we have decided against using NEventStore in production for a new project. Too many issues unfortunately -(

Comment: Have you considered using something like: https://github.com/yreynhout/AggregateSource ?  It looks better thought-through than CommonDomain.

Comment: Nope, have not seen this one. Will take a look. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Actually...I've realized this goes a bit too far in the other direction for me :-)  But it's helpful to see that you can use something other than CommonDomain with NES -- personally, I'm doing a sort of blend of a few approaches and hoping to use geteventstore.com